# Visual c++ 2010 Express won't debug a new project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

On a simple "hello world" newly created project, the built is successful, but when I click "debug" Visual c++ becomes unresponsive and nothing happens.

Note that I can see in my tasks manager several processes with my project's name, even after closing Visual c++.

If I open my previous project I can still launch it without trouble.

Comment: Someone posted a similar problem a while back, and that issue was related to Avast anti-virus software.

Comment: Indeed, turning off Avast solves the problem ... I can't understand why it only happens on some projects though :-/
Thank you very much, I would never have figured it out by myself !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user "rcgldr" gave the answer in comment, the problem comes from the Avast anti-virus software. Turning it off solves the issue.